# How to check if label of view exist in MonkeyTalk automated testing

Tags: android, testing, automated-tests, monkeytalk

I recently started writing a detail **automated test script** on **MonkeyTalk** for my application. I am fascinated with the power of this tool, but there is a small issue i am facing.

I am writing a **data driven test** case using csv file which is running file. But now I want to induct some **verification** on view, I believe that could be done using javascript but I couldn't be able to work it around. Can anyone show me how.

Here is what i am doing :

1) my script file to run the data driven test case for csv file

```
Script DataDrivenLogin.mt RunWith login.csv
```

2) my other script file where i am using the views

```
load("libs/MyApp.js");
MyApp.DataDrivenLogin.prototype.run = function(email, _password) {
    /**
     * @type MT.Application
     */
    var app = this.app;

    email = (email != undefined && email != "*" ? email : "<email>");
    _password = (_password != undefined && _password != "*" ? _password : "<_password>");

    app.image("email").tap();
    app.input("Email Address").tap({timeout:"2000"});
    app.input("Email Address").enterText(email, {timeout:"2000"});
    app.input("Password").tap({timeout:"2000"});
    app.input("Password").enterText(_password, {timeout:"2000"});
    app.button("login").tap({timeout:"2000"});
    try {
        app.image("Open").verify(); //if label exists
    } catch(Exception) {
        app.debug().print("Label not found");
    }
    app.image("Open").tap({timeout:"2000"});
    app.table("left_drawer").selectIndex("8", {timeout:"2000"});
    app.button("Yes").tap({timeout:"2000"});
    app.image("Open").tap({timeout:"2000"});
};
```

but it is not working **my script is still breaking** what I want to do is that if the view doesn't exists the script won't break and start from top again for next data value.

Help is much appreciated. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understood the problem here, if label does not exist then this

```
app.image("Open").tap({timeout:"2000"});
```

will also break. Try to put this as well in try block.

As

```
........
app.input("Password").enterText(_password, {timeout:"2000"});
    app.button("login").tap({timeout:"2000"});
    try {
        app.image("Open").verify(); //if label exists
        app.image("Open").tap({timeout:"2000"});
    } catch(Exception) {
        app.debug().print("Label not found");
    }
    app.table("left_drawer").selectIndex("8", {timeout:"2000"});
    app.button("Yes").tap({timeout:"2000"});
    app.image("Open").tap({timeout:"2000"});
```

Comment: thanks a lot i will try it for sure and accept your answer